# Setting a field of a class in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have this class:

```
public class SortingModel<T> where T : System.IComparable {
    private readonly List<T> _input;
    private List<T> _inputCopy;

    public SortingModel(List<T> parameter) {
        _inputCopy = _input = parameter;
    }
}
```

In the following function, the _input field changed along with _inputCopy, but I don't know why.

```
public void Foo()
{
   for(Int32 j = 0; j < _inputCopy.Count; ++j)
   {
       T temp = _inputCopy[j];
       _inputCopy[j] = _inputCopy[j + 1];
       _inputCopy[j + 1] = temp;
      //_input changes there, too
   }
}
```

I execute the function as `var op = ThreadPool.RunAsync(delegate { _model.Foo(); });`.
So the question is, why does _input change?

Comment: You never actually copied anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning  `_input` and `_inputCopy` to the same parameter, you are pointing them both to the same list. Any changes to the list will be visible to all references.

If you want to make a (shallow) copy of the elements of `parameter`, you can create a new list for `_inputCopy`:

```
    public SortingModel(List<T> parameter) {
        _input = parameter;
        _inputCopy = new List<T>(parameter);
    }
```

I suspect you might also need to change your loop termination to `j < _inputCopy.Count - 1`  since otherwise `_inputCopy[j + 1]` will overrun.

As an aside, use of `readonly` here just means that once the `List<>` fields `_input` and `_inputCopy` are assigned in the constructor, the fields cannot be reassigned. It doesn't mean that the contents of the list can't be changed (and if `T` is a reference type, then `T` elements can still be mutated, which will also be visible to any variable which has a reference to this `T`).

Comment: Thank you, the loop condition is correct in the program, I just copied it incorrectly. I used `_inputCopy.AddRange(_input);`

Answer (score 2):

Because in .NET arrays are reference types, so your `_input` and `_inputCopy` point to the same actual array in memory.